# Porting Haskell list comprehensions to Standard ML

Tags: haskell, sml

Out of curiosity, I'm porting the Haskell exercises of [Programming in Haskell](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/%7Epszgmh/pih.html) by Graham Hutton to Standard ML. At the beginning everything seemed pretty similar until I reached list comprehensions:

> A triple `(x,y,z)` of positive integers is called *pythagorean* if `x2 + y2 = z2`. Using a list comprehension, define a function `pyths ∷ Int → [(Int,Int,Int)]` that maps an integer `n` to all such triples with components in `[1..n]`.

The Haskell version is pretty simple:

```hs
pyths ∷ Int → [(Int, Int, Int)]
pyths n = [(x, y, z) |
  x ← [1..n],
  y ← [1..n],
  z ← [1..n],
  x^2 + y^2 == z^2]
```

My Standard ML attempt, not so much:

```ml
(* No list comprehensions in SML so we need a helper function *)
val generateIntsUpTo = fn n =>
  let val rec helper = fn current => fn xs =>
    if current <= n
    (* then current :: helper (current + 1) xs *)
    then helper (current + 1) (current :: xs)
    else xs
  in
    rev (helper 1 [])
  end

(* Now we can find the pyths *)
val pyths = fn n =>
  let
    val numbers = generateIntsUpTo n
  in
    foldr (fn (x, acc) =>
      foldr (fn (y, acc) =>
        foldr (fn (z, acc) =>
          if x * x + y * y = z * z
          then (x, y, z) :: acc
          else acc
        ) acc numbers
      ) acc numbers
    ) [] numbers
  end
```

The first thing that I don't like is the call to `rev` at the end of `generateIntsUpTo` but I did it to accomplish a tail recursive function. Commented out is the line that lets me avoid the reversion of the list but then it's not tail recursive.

Besides that, there's the three nested `foldr` calls. I have been thinking of writing my own recursive functions, but I wanted to do this with the minimum amount of custom code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Feedback:**

- The Haskell `pyths` is not very efficient, and it contains duplicate answers.
- `fun` instead of `val`/`val rec` is syntactic sugar for function declarations.
- Instead of `generateIntsUpTo n`, use `List.tabulate (n, fn i => i+1)`.
- Using `rev` to achieve a tail-recursive function can be a good choice. Neither SML/NJ's or Moscow ML's `List.tabulate` is tail-recursive, though. If you're worrying about performance here, consider the fact that you don't actually need to store these numbers in lists -- this is purely a convenience so that you can use list comprehensions to iterate their combinations.

**Pythagorean triples in Standard ML**

> I wanted to do it using the minimum amount of custom code.

To achieve the same efficiency as the Haskell `pyths` and use the minimum amount of custom code, here is one version that uses `List.filter`, `List.concat` and `List.tabulate`:

```
fun isPythTriple (x, y, z) = x*x + y*y = z*z
fun tab1 n f = List.tabulate (n, fn i => f (i+1))
fun pyths n =
    List.filter isPythTriple (
      List.concat (tab1 n (fn x =>
      List.concat (tab1 n (fn y =>
                   tab1 n (fn z => (x,y,z)))))))
```

This takes several seconds for `pyths 10`; there really is not reason to generate *O(n³)* list elements when the solution subset is so sparse.

> I have been thinking on write my own recursive functions

Writing your own helper functions is really not something that should be avoided. Generally, using library functions is good, but Standard ML's library is somewhat limited. For example, `List.tabulate` can't iterate a range of numbers without generating the list in memory. And as you're hinting at, the multiple nested `foldr`s does not make the code particularly readable.

You could for example combine `List.tabulate` and `List.filter` to reduce memory consumption:

```
fun tabfilter (from, to, f) =
    if from > to then [] else
      case f from of
           SOME value => value :: tabfilter (from+1, to, f)
         | NONE       =>          tabfilter (from+1, to, f)

fun isPythTriple (x, y, z) = x*x + y*y = z*z

fun pyths n =
    List.concat (tabfilter (1, n, fn x =>
      SOME (List.concat (tabfilter (1, n, fn y =>
        SOME (tabfilter (1, n, fn z => Option.filter isPythTriple (x, y, z))))))))
```

This runs orders of magnitude faster. Still, it is a little convoluted.

A plain recursive version:

```
fun isPythTriple (x, y, z) = x*x + y*y = z*z
fun pyths n =
    let fun loop (0, _, _) = []
          | loop (x, 0, _) = loop (x-1, n, n)
          | loop (x, y, 0) = loop (x, y-1, n)
          | loop (t as (x, y, z)) =
            if isPythTriple t then t :: loop (x,y,z-1) else loop (x,y,z-1)
    in rev (loop (n, n, n)) end
```

And a tail-recursive variant of the same:

```
fun isPythTriple x y z = x*x + y*y = z*z
fun pyths n =
    let fun loop 0 _ _ res = res
          | loop x 0 _ res = loop (x-1) n n res
          | loop x y 0 res = loop x (y-1) n res
          | loop x y z res =
            let val res' = if isPythTriple x y z
                           then (x,y,z) :: res
                           else res
            in loop x y (z-1) res'
            end
    in loop n n n [] end
```